# Is there a way in SQL Server Management Studio to view field data in a multi-line editable field?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a database that I am viewing with SQL Server Management Studio **2008**.

I right-click on the table and choose **edit top 200 rows**.

I tab over to my "SerializedXML" **varchar(max)** field that has **100s of lines of data** in it but I am only able to move back and forth in it with my cursor in a tiny **one-line** textbox.

I remember there being no alternative to this back in SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager, but thought it might have **changed** by now.

**Is there any way I can view/edit this field in a mutli-line textbox?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is already discussed.

[How to easily edit SQL XML column in SQL Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026/how-to-easily-edit-sql-xml-column-in-sql-management-studio)

As everybody says over there, I will vote to write small tool.

Here is one third party tool

http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/sql-server-xml.html

may be give try to trial version.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, I looked around for a while and gave up (was storing XML also). Only thing I can suggest is copy-paste between notepad and the cell.

Comment: exactly, I've been copying and pasting like this since 2000. Perhaps this is a "feature" which encourages developers to write applications based on SQL Server so they can edit their data. :-)

Comment: Pasting a multiline text in an edit cell is not possible on SSMS. It will only paste the first line of what you are pasting. You can copy multiline texts from them though. What I do is use Insert and Update statements which do accept multiline text. Developing an application would be the best solution I guess.