# Efficiently access long text from a column in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Newbie question: I'm using SQL Server on a remote server where I cannot use UDFs of any type. I am using a database where one column is a text column containing several paragraphs of text per entry. As I test my code, I would like to have a way to efficiently access these columns a few at a time.

Currently, the only way I can find to do this is using eg:

```
SELECT TOP 25 ReportText 
FROM MyDb.Table1
```

...which, of course, gives the output in the `Results` window, as a single string of characters that I have to keep dragging the column width wider and wider and wider in order to try to see.

What am I missing? I don't need it to look pretty, I just need to be able to see it efficiently....

Comment: Have you tried results to text (ctrl +t)?

Comment: Try the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8827253/243373) on SO, see if you can use that...

Comment: Results to text was exactly what I needed.  How has this command been missing from my life (and my many google searches)?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JohnSpecko pointed out in a comment, results to text is exactly what I needed.  It is turned on by hitting (ctrl+t) before running your query.  Thanks!

Comment: John, I am a total newbie in terms of how 'credit' works here - I put this in the answer field just so people would see that this had an answer and not spend more time on it, but if you post the same thing as an answer I'm happy to "checkmark" your answer and delete mine.  I appreciated your help - this has been bugging me for an embarrassingly long time!

Comment: if you want other user see the message include and @ following the name , like `@JohnSpecko` only work if user already wrote there.